# Authorization by AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget waits infinit time

Tags: macos, qt, cocoa, automation, macos-mojave

I use this method to check Apple Event (Automation) permission:

```
bool checkSIPforAppIdentifier(const QString &appId)
{
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    if (@available(macOS 10.14, *)) {

        NSAppleEventDescriptor *targetAppEventDescriptor;

        targetAppEventDescriptor = [NSAppleEventDescriptor descriptorWithBundleIdentifier:appId.toNSString()];

        status = AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget(targetAppEventDescriptor.aeDesc, typeWildCard, typeWildCard, true);
    }

    return status == noErr;
}
```

The problem is that the execution freezes at API: **AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget** and the user is not prompted for authorization.

usage example:

```
checkSIPforAppIdentifier("com.microsoft.Word");
```

I have inserted necessary key in info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>XXX uses this feature to do do Typography actions.</string>
```

My App is not sandboxed.

Comment: Did you got any solution , me too facing same issue  AEDeterminePermissionToAutomateTarget waits forever to return OSStatus.

Comment: @MacDeveloper : This is probably due to a corrupted signature of the origin or destination bundle. It is better to call this method via thread.

Comment: Did it worked for you , I moved it to background thread but no luck

Comment: @MacDeveloper Yes it works, I get descriptor param as: AECreateDesc(typeProcessSerialNumber, &psn,
           sizeof(psn), &targetDesc), not using NSAppleEventDescriptor

Comment: did you ever find a solution? we also have two customers reporting endless freezing at this API call...

Answer (score -3):

Hardened Runtime open Apple Events
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cYO.png)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on how your answer solves the problem for the OP?